# An answer which cannot be accepted

Tags: support, accepted-answer, migrated-questions

I spotted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726345/ascii-character-encoding-issue) -- a simple case of Basically Bad Coding, and so I went and posted an answer to it. So did a couple of others.

But, much to my suprise, I don't believe the poster can mark *any* of the answers as "correct" ... he doesn't appear to have an SO account!

Does this mean the question cannot but remain "open" for all eternity?

Comment: The user might not be aware yet that his question has been migrated. If he follows the link he will be able to view it, he will have the option of logging in and associating his account from Prog.SE with a new SO one, he will also get a rep bonus if he does so (and he'll be able to mark an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean the question cannot but remain "open" for all eternity?

Yes, unless the OP of the question creates an account / login to Stack Overflow and accepts an answer.

> I don't believe the poster can mark any of the answers as "correct" ... he doesn't appear to have an SO account!

Its because the question was migrated from Programmers.SE where the OP has an account. User accounts don't get migrated when a post is moved to another site.

Comment: If the OP does end up creating an account on Stack Overflow, they would then be able to accept an answer.

Comment: Alas. Looking at his profile, I get this sinking feeling it *will* remain un-accepted until all electrons in the universe have decayed.

Comment: Why should you care? Questions don't need to have accepted answers.

Comment: Well, ideally, I think they should. Only the rhetorical and the opinion based questions cannot be definitely answered.